# What are the exact odds of getting a perfect NCAA bracket?

Tags: probability

With the NCAA March Madness Finals nearing, I thought it'd be appropriate to ask this.

From everything that I've read and heard online, there seems to be varying opinions on the exact odds of getting a perfect NCAA bracket, especially from different sources.  That seems certainly strange, because I had originally thought there'd be only one way to calculate the odds of that.

For example, [this link](http://www.omaha.com/article/20140121/MONEY/140129816) seems to suggest the odds are 9.2 quintillion. Which seems odd that, compared with [this](http://www.freep.com/article/20120313/SPORTS08/120313043/ncaa-tournament-perfect-bracket), suggesting it's around 4 quadrillion.  Which leads me to being somewhat confused as to the exact number for the odds.

What I'm **far more interested is how do I calculate the chances** of getting a perfect bracket? With 68 possible winners, I had originally thought it'd be a simple `68!`, but I thought since there were a total possible of 68 slots, it could be `68 ^ 68`?  Is my thinking off, or am I somewhere in the right court?

Comment: Your first link assumes only 64 teams.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say there's you have a chance of around 1 in 147 quintillion.  More specifically, there are 67 games, since all but one of the 68 must lose.  Thus, *assuming* you pick all your games with the flip of a coin, you've got a probability of $1/2^{67} = 1/147573952589676412928$ of picking everything correctly.

The computation is fairly simple.  I'm assuming that the odds of picking a single game correctly are 50-50 or a probability of $1/2$.  I'm also assuming that the choices are independent of one another so that their joint probabilities can be [computed via multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#For_events).  We then simply multiply 67 one-halves together to get the result.

Your [first link](http://www.omaha.com/article/20140121/MONEY/140129816) points to a [USA Today article](http://www.usatoday.com/story/gameon/2013/03/19/ncaa-tournament-perfect-bracket-odds-quintillion/1999795/) which in turn points to a [page on Geekosystem](http://www.geekosystem.com/odds-of-perfect-bracket/) which shows an image of a Depaul mathematics professor standing in front of a white board with the computation $2^{63} = 9223372036854775808$.  That suggests that the 9 quintillion number refers to the smaller 64 team bracket we had prior to the play-in games.  My computation arises from the larger bracket that includes four play-in games.

**Edit**: It might be worth mentioning that most online bracket challenge games start *after* the play in games and, therefore, use the 64 team bracket.

Of course, some folks might be better than 50-50 at picking basketball games.  Let's suppose you can pick a winner three fourths of the time.  (Note that, earlier this month, Sports Illustrated's [Seth Davis was 36 of 50](http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/college-basketball/news/20140103/weekend-picks-iowa-wisconsin-oregon-colorado-san-diego-state-kansas/index.html) or just 72%.)  Then, your odds would be $(3/4)^{67}$ or about 1 in 234 million.  Still not very good.

Comment: Of course, one would hope that you have a better method than randomly selecting the winner of each game!  Even more so after Nate Silver's use of statistics in predicting winners last year.

Comment: @SpamIAm I was just thinking about that and editing my post accordingly! :)

Comment: I think your second paragraph is very informative. +1

Comment: @SpamIAm can you provide a link?

Comment: So how did you reach that conclusion? I'm just curious in the methodology

Comment: @Retrosaur I expanded my answer a bit. I hope that helps.

Comment: @EmmetB [Here's a link to his blog](http://fivethirtyeight.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/03/19/nate-silver-on-the-n-c-a-a-bracket/).