# Computing basketball team rankings with eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For an assignment, we've been asked to compute a ranking of basketball teams by finding the eigenvector of a matrix $A$ corresponding to $A$'s maximal eigenvalue (ie, using the power iteration method). The matrix $A$ is given to us, and all we have to do is implement the power method, but I'm curious as to why what we're computing would yield a sensible ranking?

The matrix $A$ is constructed like so: All relevant teams are mapped to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. If team $i$ played team $j$ and won by $6$ or less, then $A_{i,j} = 0.4$ and $A_{j,i} = 0.5$. If team $i$ won by more than $6$, then $$A_{j,i} = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-d)}$$ where $d$ is the score difference.

$A_{i,j} = 0$ for all other $1 \le i,j \le n$.

Then, if $v$ is the eigenvector of $A$ with maximal eigenvalue, the entries of $v$ correspond to the rankings of the team. Why would this be a sensible ranking scheme?

**edit**: In the case where a team wins by more than $6$, I *suspect* the intent was to also set $A_{i,j} = 1 - A_{j,i}$, as this value was computed in the code given to us, but never actually assigned to the matrix. I'm unsure if this was a mistake or if $A_{i,j}$ should remain $0$ in that case.

Comment: For games played, $A_{ij}+A_{ji}=1$ follows directly from the computation formula, since for the score difference, when using indices, $d_{ij}=-d_{ji}$.

Comment: @LutzL The difference is the absolute value of the difference -- each game is processed only once.

Comment: Yes, and $1-\frac1{1+e^{-d}}=1-\frac{e^d}{1+e^d}=\frac1{1+e^{-(-d)}}$. But since it is not used in the matrix,... Of course, you could play with it and investigate what happens in case that this value is used in the matrix.

Comment: @LutzL Okay, assuming the $1 - A_{j,i}$ is included in the matrix, and also ignoring the fact that for score differences less than 6 we have $A_{i,j} + A_{j,i} = 0.9 \neq 1$, what would having $A_{i,j} + A_{j,i} = 1$ for all $i,j$ where $i$ played $j$, what would this tell us about the eigenvector?

Comment: Related with standard technique and links: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/710864/115115

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea of ranking by eigenvectors is a translation from a "plus-max arithmetic" (or [max-plus algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-plus_algebra)) to normal arithmetic.

The idea in "plus-max arithmetic" is that the rank of a player should be bigger than the rank of all other players over which they have won, adding some distance for the decisiveness of the win. Adding a degree of freedom for the separation of the ranks (resp. to uniformly adjust the distances) gives the formula
$$
r_i=s+\max_{j:p_i>p_j}(r_j+d_{i,j})
$$

where $p_j>p_i$ means "player $i$ played and won against player $j$". 
Setting $d_{i,j}=-\infty$ for games not played or lost by player $i$ gives the generalized formula
$$
r_i=s+\max_{j}(r_j+d_{i,j}).
$$

An approximate translation from "plus-max" to normal arithmetic is via exponentiation
$$
\exp(r_i)\approx\exp(s)\sum_{j}\exp(r_j)\cdot \exp(d_{i,j})
$$
which is now in eigenvector form. Set $v_i=\exp(r_i)$, $A_{i,j}=\exp(d_{i,j})$ if $p_i>p_j$, with $\exp(-\infty)=0$, and $\lambda=\exp(-s)$, the usual form of an eigenvalue equation follows,
$$\lambda v=Av.$$
A maximal eigenvalue that is bigger than one (i.e., $s<0$) would need some explaining, more precisely, $s+d_{ij}$ should be positive for games won. If this is not the case, the winner in some games might get a lower rank than the loser. Which might be a sensible outcome in more complex situations.

---

Changing $\exp(d)$ to $\frac{\exp(d)}{1+\exp(d)}=\frac1{1+\exp(-d)}$ changes the distance in the "plus-max" picture for games won, but since the transformation from $x$ to $\frac{x}{1+x}=1-\frac1{1+x}$ is via a monotically increasing function, it only changes the quantities, not the quality ("changing quantity" may result also in different rankings, "quality" here is just the applicability of the plus-max interpretation).

However, since 
$$
h(d)=\log(1/(1+\exp(-d))=-\log(1+\exp(-d)<0,
$$ 
the original ranking distances are negative, which has then to be compensated by $s$. One could also multiply by $2$ to get all factors for games won to be larger than 1, this only changes the eigenvalue or $s$.

---

Inclusion of the lost games could have the reasoning that tightly losing against a strong player is comparable or better than winning against a weak player, which could be interpreted via the "plus-max" formula
$$
r_i=s+\max\left(\max_{j:p_i>p_j}(r_j+h(d_{i,j})),\max_{j:p_i<p_j}(r_j+h(-d_{j,i}))\right)
$$
One could of course also use a different formula than $d_{ij}=-d_{ji}$ for games lost, or have $h(-x)$ unrelated to $h(x)$ in
$$
r_i=s+\max_{j}(r_j+h(d_{i,j}))
$$ 
so that games lost have a weaker influence on the rank than games won.