# NCAA bracket and binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Given that March Madness is almost here I was trying to figure out the probability of constructing a perfect bracket if you just flipped a coin for every game. I came up with two possible solutions.

1. The tournament is basically just 63 disjoint events, so (1/2)^63
2. Alternatively, each round can be viewed as a set of binomial events, in which case I thought that $\binom{64}{32}\binom{32}{16}\binom{16}{8}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}$ would get me the same answer (each of those is a binomial coefficient)

However, each of these gives substantially different results. Googling for answers suggests that the first version is the correct one, as does this post

[What are the exact odds of getting a perfect NCAA bracket?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648321/what-are-the-exact-odds-of-getting-a-perfect-ncaa-bracket)

So my question is, why is the second answer so different? It seems like that is also a reasonable description of what's going on, but the answer is multiple orders of magnitude too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is too large because you are counting combinations that are not possible in the bracket. Look at just $\binom{4}{2}$ for the semi-finals. Let's say that teams $A$ and $B$ are in the left bracket and play each other in a semi-final game and teams $C$ and $D$ are in the right bracket and play each other in a semi-final game. Then the only possible match-ups we can have for the championship are $A-C$, $A-D$, $B-C$, $B-D$. But $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ because it also counts the match-ups $A-B$ and $C-D$ which are valid choices of a subset but not valid based on the bracket structure.